# What is a concrete example of Android app functionality that uses HashMap?

Tags: android, hashmap

I am a beginner in Android, and understand only very basically that `HashMap` class enables key/value pairs. But how does this translate into actually using this in an Android app? Could someone provide a simple, plain English example of what case you might want to use `HashMap` in an app? I cannot imagine a case where I might need it. Make up an Android app idea, if needed. Thanks in advance.

I am looking for a "big picture" analysis that will give some examples where you might use HashMap with certain Android functionalities you are trying to implement.

Comment: I really don't understand what is wrong with this question.

Comment: Downvotes without explanations do nothing for the StackOverflow community. If you want more information, or want me to reword my question, I would be happy to do that, if you would only point out what the difficulty is you are having with my question.

Comment: First let me clear one thing. Not downvoted your question and another thing it's dependent on your app and you want to used `HashMap`.

Comment: SimplePlan, I was not necessarily suggesting you downvoted, although thanks for letting me know, I was just talking to the people who did the downvote. Okay, so it will depend on your app, but when I ask myself the question, "when will I ever use HashMap?" I cannot think of an idea to use it. So I was just hoping others who have used it could share the examples of what kind of functionality they used it for. I do not know enough Android to know this, and looking up "HashMap examples in Android" on Google only shows me code, it does not explain what it does or what it will produce.

Comment: And a CS question is not allowed on here? There are a lot of people who have no CS degree who are trying to learn Android. So it would be wise to be patient with them, perhaps provide links, whatever you think it would take to help someone learn. I know I am not the only person learning Android without a CS background. I go to meetups a lot and they are filled with aspiring programmers who have no CS background.

Comment: @NoniA. the point is not about aspiring cs people. You need to go to help center and know how this site works http://stackoverflow.com/help.

Comment: Thanks Raghun... for that link, but I read through the questions not to ask, and the guidelines for the questions to ask, and I did not find any fault with my question, as it related to Android and an Android class, specifically, it is just that it had some CS background (but what question doesn't?) and so the focus seemed to shift to CS. When really it was about Android, and an example of how to use it. If I need to know more CS to understand the answer to my question, I don't see why someone's answer could not include that. I thought Aviad did a great job answering my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HashMap or Map interface is not new on android, This is Java Collections framework.
Java collection are meant to be used in several cases to hold data and contain 3 interfaces:

1. List - Basically simple list,or linked list implementations
2. Set - The same as list but won't hold 2 equal obejcts(You need to implement you own equals and hashcode)
3. Map - as you said key value pair.

Uses:
List - For anything, just to hold data
Set - For list of data that we want that all of the items will be unique.
Map - Key value and the most common example is the use for DB items, or something with ids.. for example:
bookId, Book.. I that case you can take the object by id.. This is the most common

I attached link for Java collection tutorial.. It is very important framework that you have to know if you are going to develop java/android

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/index.html

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks Aviad! That was a thorough and well-explained answer. I will go through these tutorials. I didn't realize collections was such a large topic, but very good to know. I am glad you pointed out that there are 3 kinds of `HashMap`s and thanks for stressing its importance in studying Android. I really appreciated it.

Comment: NP.. But there are no 3 kind of HashMap.. There are 3 Type of Collections :). HaspMap is implementation for the Map<T> interface. You have to read this article.. It is one of the important and must know framework in java.. Good luck :)

Comment: Oops, thanks! I most definitely will read this, asap. :)

Answer (score 1):

We could use `HashMap` to keep a list of employess together with their respective salaries.

We can do:

```
HashMap<String, Float> emplMap = new HashMap<String, Float>();

emplMap.put("fred", 1.000);

for(String name : emplMap.keySet()) {
   System.out.print(name + "'s salary is" + emplMap.get(name));
}
```

Should print

> "fred's salary 1.000"

Comment: Thanks Alex, so then `HashMap` handles lists, where you want to use information from the list, correct? But then why not use ArrayList? Although I can't say I know a lot about `ArrayList` either, but just trying to understand the unique advantage of using `HashMap`. Is it so you can create a bunch of key value pairs and then get them, set them, or do other things with them when you need to?

Comment: You could get yourself a book such as Thinking in Java. From that book you will learn things proper way and will understand everything. A very good book.